# Angular 8 - How to query DOM elements by their attributes?

Tags: angular, renderer

I have a dynamically generated an HTML 5 table using the renderer2:

```
const td = this.renderer.createElement('td');
this.renderer.setProperty(td, 'id', letter + i);
this.renderer.setAttribute(td, 'contenteditable', 'true');
this.renderer.setAttribute(td, 'r', i + '');
this.renderer.setAttribute(td, 'c', j + '');
```

The table has the following structure

```
<table _ngcontent-iji-c1="" appcreatereport="">
<tr _ngcontent-iji-c1="">
<td _ngcontent-iji-c1="">1</td>
<td _ngcontent-iji-c1="" id="A1" contenteditable="true" r="1" c="1"></td>
<td _ngcontent-iji-c1="" id="B1" contenteditable="true" r="1" c="2"></td>
<td _ngcontent-iji-c1="" id="C1" contenteditable="true" r="1" c="3"></td>
<td _ngcontent-iji-c1="" id="D1" contenteditable="true" r="1" c="4"></td>
<td _ngcontent-iji-c1="" id="E1" contenteditable="true" r="1" c="5"></td>
</tr>
...
```

Each `<td>`has an "id", a row number "r" and a column number "c"

I am trying to work with angular only (so no jquery) and I have looked at many existing data grids, but they are never fully covering what I plan to do and extending them seems more complicated than building exactly what I need.

I have two questions.

1. My undertanding is that I am not supposed to manipulate the DOM directly in Angular, how can I access elements if they don't have a local reference ? (or how can I add a local reference when I generate the `<td`> elements in the renderer2. Text in `<TD>` will need to be updated, for example when I do a copy/paste from excel.
2. How can I query an element by attributes, so I want the  element where r=1 and c= 4 (instead of query by id "D1"). I only found @ViewChild which only works with references.

I am currently setting the text of a TD element the following way:

```
(document.getElementById(
          'C1'
        ) as HTMLTableDataCellElement).innerHTML = '123;
```

How can I do that in a more "Angular" way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to change design to use table with array of elements and `*ngFor`. 
To remove it from the page you can use `*ngIf="elements.length === 0"`;

```
let elements = [{r:1, c: 1, value:''}, {r:1, c: 2, value:''} ... ];
elements[1].value = '123';

<td *ngFor="let el of elements" [r] = "el.r" [c]="el.c">{{el.value}}<\td>
```

In such case you'll have access to each `td` values directly using elements array.

As an alternative - `ng-template` can be used to keep table in html but not shown till needed.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but will that update help me update specific cells. Imagine that I have a table with 200 rows and 20 columns and want to paste some data somewhere in the middle of the file.

Comment: For such table you can have array with 200 entries with 20 properties for each entry. And just update specific value. That is Angular style approach.
Or just 2-dimensional array with 200 entries. Actually it doesn't matter how much rows/cells you have.

Comment: Thank you, I created a 2 dimensional array and used two *ngFor for the rows and the columns. I can then set the values but still have challenges to detect changes: The "td" are editable and a user can change input.

Comment: To detect changes  add some (change)="onChange(el)" handler, which passes element as input parameter. If element has value type(not reference type), you may pass row and column indexes

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly unclear what you want. But here is a shot at a [few scenarios](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygutef):

1. Selecting a check box filters the list
2. Clicking an item updates another element with the value

First just a dummy class:

```
  export class RowData {
  Name:string;
  Id:number;
  Row:number;
  Column: number;
  Visible: boolean = true;
}
```

With dummy data:

```
items: RowData[] = [
         {
          Name: "One",
          Id:1,
          Row:1,
          Column:1,
          Visible:true,
        },
        {
          Name: "Two",
          Id:2,
          Row:2,
          Column:2,
          Visible:true,
        },
        {
          Name: "Another Row",
          Id:5,
          Row:3,
          Column:3,
          Visible:true,
        },
        {
          Name: "Yep",
          Id:4,
          Row:4,
          Column:4,
          Visible:true,
        },
      ]
    }
```

For the view I have two way binding with a couple events:

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Toggle Row" (click)="toggleRows()" /> Toggle Rows <br>  
</div>
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div (click)="showMe(item)" *ngIf=item.Visible>{{item.Name}}</div>
</div>

<label *ngIf="clicked">{{clicked.Name}}</label>
```

And here are the events and their dependent properties:

```
toggleRow2Col2: boolean = true;
  clicked: RowData;

  showMe(elem){
    this.clicked = elem;
  }

  toggleRows(){
    this.toggleRow2Col2 = !this.toggleRow2Col2;

    if (!this.toggleRow2Col2){    
    this.items.forEach(function(item){
      if (item.Row != 2 && item.Column != 2){
        item.Visible = false;
      }
    })
    }

    else {
      this.items.forEach(function(item)      {
          item.Visible = true;
      })
    }
  }
```

The idea is that yes, we can filter and change the DOM, just by attributes and binding and **not** by JS / JQuery.